# GTX 970 stopped working, but GT 710 works

Tags: graphics-card

I tried connecting my computer to a projector and my GTX 970 stopped working. It doesn't work on boot, WIndows or Ubuntu. But when I put GT 710 (same and the only PCI slot), that works. My setup is as follows-

Motherboard: zebronics zeb h61 (I know, not conventional)
Power Supply: EVGA 500 W

**Note:** GTX 970 shows up as 'Hidden Device' under the Device Manager on Windows.

I was wondering if it's the graphics card or the PCIE power connector?

Comment: Hi Speedracer, welcome to the site! Unfortunately debugging issues with graphics cards is a little out of Arqade's scope, I'll migrate your question to our sister-site, Super User SE, which is better suited to help you. :-)

Comment: Have you tried connecting the GTX 970 onto another computer to see if it's broken?

Comment: You want to go into the BIOS and look for a setting called Legacy PCI. Toggle this setting, and reboot with the GT710. Now remove the 710, re-install the 970 and reboot. I have the same issue with my 750TI, and have to use my GTS450 to restore normal service.

Comment: Thank you @Robotnik.

Comment: @iBug I was going to, fortunately it started working before I gave up reinstalling it.

Comment: @spikey_richie, I removed all usb devices and then reinstalled the GTX970 twice and now it works. I have no idea why.

Comment: In that case, you may have triggered a BIOS restore from a last known good backup (the last time it successfully booted), which happened to reset something which was preventing a boot.